# More efficient way to create an array of objects using puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

I'm trying to **scrape** a page that contains a bunch of text messages. The messages are arrange in a similar manner to the example below. I would like to use puppeeter to create an array of objects. Each object would contain the inner text of each message excluding one of the elements.

The array I would like to build should look like:

```
const messages = [{name: 'Greg', textMessage: 'Blah Blah Blah'}, {name: 'James', textMessage: 'Blah Blah Blah'},{name: 'Sam', textMessage: 'Blah Blah Blah'}]
```

Example: HTML markup

```
<div class="messages">
  <div class="message">
    <a class="name">Greg</a>
    <p class="element-you-dont-want">Don't scrape this</p>
    <p class="textMessage">Blah Blah Blah</p>
  </div>
  <div class="message">
    <a class="name">James</a>
    <p class="element-you-dont-want">Don't scrape this</p>
    <p class="textMessage">Blah Blah Blah</p>
  </div>
  <div class="message">
    <a class="name">Sam</a>
    <p class="element-you-dont-want">Don't scrape this</p>
    <p class="textMessage">Blah Blah Blah</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

My current code creates two arrays, one for names the other for the textMessages, then I have to combine them. Is there a more efficient way to do this.

```
 const names = await page.evaluate(
      () =>  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("div.messages a.name")).map(name => name.innerText)
    );
    const textMessages = await page.evaluate(
      () =>  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("div.messages p.textMessage")).map(textMessage => textMessage.innerText)
    );

... From here I combine the two into an object of arrays.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an `$$eval` function in `Page`, which translates to `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector))` within the context and passes it as the first argument to `pageFunction`.

Usage:

```
const result = await page.$$eval('div.message', (msgs) => msgs.map((msg) => {
            return {
                name: msg.querySelector('a.name').innerText,
                textMessage: msg.querySelector('a.textMessage').innerText
            }})
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can scrape them together,

```
page.evaluate(() => {
  const messages = [...document.querySelectorAll("div.message")]; // notice this is not .messages
  return messages.map(message => {
      return {
        name: message.querySelector('a.name').innerText,
        textMessage: message.querySelector('a.textMessage').innerText
      }
    }
  }
});
```